# Chart.js - get x-axis label (or index) in onHover event

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way to get the x-axis label (or index since not every step is labelled) in the onHover event? I know about getElementsAtEventForMode, getElementsAtXAxis, getElementAtEvent, etc. But I don't want the elements. I just want to know where along the x-axis the mouse is at that point.

Answer (score -1):

```
onHover: function (evt) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
    if (x > myChart.chartArea.right)
        x = myChart.chartArea.right;
    const dataX = myChart.scales["x-axis-0"].getValueForPixel(x);
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.